# Public alias for non-public type

Tags: c++, alias, access-modifiers

I wonder if it is valid C++ :

```
class Test {
    struct PrivateInner {
        PrivateInner(std::string const &str) {
            std::cout << str << "\n";
        }
    };

public:
    using PublicInner = PrivateInner;
};

//Test::PrivateInner priv("Hello world");        // Ok, private so we can't use that
Test::PublicInner publ("Hello World");           // ?, by using public alias we can access private type, is it ok ?
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the code be valid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Types* are neither public nor private. Access control only ever applies to *names*. Since `PublicInner` is a public *name* that refers to the `PrivateInner` class, it can be used outside the `Test` class.